# Magento 2.2.2 not showing ship option for some orders

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

[image]

In Magento 2.2.2 I have sent shipment mails for more than 10 orders, but for some orders there is no ship option showing on top right, how can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It happens in case your product does not have any weight.
When I product does not have any weight assigned it becomes a virtual product and virtual products cannot be shipped.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened when the shipping method in the orders table did not have the correct shipping method format. It should be

```
shippingcarriername_shippingmethod
```